# What is a _least ancestor_ in Boyer Myrvolds paper?

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading the Paper "On cutting edge" by Boyer and Myrvold[1] in which I don't understand the following sentence:

> Thus, a vertex w is externally active during the processing of v if w either has a least ancestor less than v or if the first element in the separatedDFSChildList of w has a lowpoint less than v.

It can be found in the pdf in chapter/section 3, page 8, last sentence before chapter 4.

I am trying to understand the word *least ancestor* here. it was kind of defined on the previous page in the sentences:

> During preprocessing, we first obtain the least ancestor directly adjacent to each vertex by a back edge, then we compute the lowpoint of each vertex.

So, what is a least ancestor? Is there a difference between this an the *least common ancestor* (which I found when I was googling for *least ancestor*.)

[1] https://www.emis.de/journals/JGAA/accepted/2004/BoyerMyrvold2004.8.3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't yet looked at your reference, I'll give you the typical graph theoretic definitions. The terms "least ancestor" and "least common ancestor" are usually used in reference to a rooted tree, although you can extend the definitions I'm about to give to other contexts. Take your rooted tree $T$ with root $v$ and imagine it drawn "downward"; that is, $v$ is the highest vertex on the drawing, then $v$'s children are drawn below $v$, and then their children, and so on. This imagine should be familiar to CS people, so I won't elaborate anymore (let me know if you need more explanation).

Let me first begin by defining a "descendent" of a vertex in our picture. The descendent of a vertex $u$ of $T$ is any vertex that appears  "beneath" $u$, with the only route to the root being through $u$; if THE path connecting $u$ and $w$ does not have to travel upwards in our picture, then $w$ is a descendent of $u$. The "ancestor" relation is the opposite of the descendent relation: $u$ is a ancestor of $w$ if and only if $w$ is a descendant of $u$. THE "least ancestor" of $u$ is the lowest ancestor of $u$ in our picture. The least ancestor is also the ancestor of $u$ that has no other ancestors of $u$ as descendent; in other words, it is THE vertex directly above $u$ in $T$. THE least common ancestor of $u$ and $w$ is the lowest vertex that is an ancestor to both $u$ and $w$.

Least ancestor is only in reference to one vertex, whereas the least *common* ancestor is in reference to two vertices.

Comment: Good content, could use a little bit of proof-reading and rewording in parts. +1

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, thank you. I was in transit trying to pass the time, so this was written on my phone. I tried to come up with some definitions that were clear, but I can guarantee you there are better ways to define these things. Suggestions are appreciated as always.

Comment: I have to admit that I had to go through your text multiple times (since English is not my first language) but I think that I understood it. Thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: @Ctwx, it certainly takes some effort to have the definitions make sense. Once I get to a computer I can try creating some diagrams.

Comment: @Bob1123 that would be great. :-) Sorry for the late answer.